# Which files contains the implementations for malloc() and new()?

Tags: c++, c, linux, ubuntu, memory-management

On Linux (Ubuntu) what is the path and file name where I can see the C/C++ code used in the malloc() and new() implementations?

I have looked in /usr/include but started to lose my way around. Does it depend on which version of gcc/g++ I have installed?

If someone could also give a general answer which would help me understand how Linux stores all the  "native" functions it would be most appreciated and I wouldnt ever have to ask again for a different function.

Comment: You find this in the implementation of the C Standard Library the compiler uses.

Comment: Look at glibc sources: http://gnu.org/software/libc

Comment: why would you want these sources? have you search on the web? do you understand that C and C++ (there is no such thing as C/C++) are languages that get compiled to machine code?

Comment: @JensGustedt malloc() is used in C and new() is used in C++ hence the phrase "C/C++". I didn't debate they weren't compiled to machine code. I had always understood in Linux you could see all the code, within the OS, hence my question "where is the code for new()?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing: `new` is a C++ keyword that uses `malloc`.

The source for `malloc` is in the source for your version of `libc`, which is probably `glibc`. Look at their source.

Other built in functions that are *system* calls only have shell implementations in `glibc` that call the underlying syscall.

Comment: @user997112: No, I just mean the code for `glibc`, the GNU libc implementation.

Comment: @Linuxios- how can I find this in my Ubuntu filesystem? As in to open the file containing the C/C++ for the functions above? When I search for glibc I just have a folder full of .so files.

Comment: @user: they aren't local. You have to download the c source code that compiles into those .so files.

Comment: @Linuxios btw, when you compile in static, you won't load the .so files. How and what the compiler do in that case?

Comment: @Maxime: I don't quite understand

Comment: @Linuxios, as an example, write a hello world in C and compile it. If you run strace on the binary, you'll see it loads libc.so. Now if you compile in static, there is no .so loading. I suppose the compiler need the printf code in that case, am I right?

Comment: @Maxime: If you compile statically, the necessary code from `libc.so` is included in the output file (I think). That's why statically compiled binarys are so over sized and wasteful.

Comment: @Linuxios that's exactly my point: "the necessary code from libc.so is included in the output file" => so it copies the already compiled code. I was wondering if the source code (in C) of the functions were available to the compiler or if the compiler were using the libc.so from the system to retrieve the code (in static mode).

Comment: @Maxime: It is not using the C code, but rather the object file (.so, .o, etc.). No source code from the library is involved (by the way, I'm not sure if it just copies the whole library or just part).

Comment: I've accepted your answer but it was actually your comment which answered it :)

Comment: @user997112 Glad to help any way I can.

Comment: @Linuxios Given the size of a static binary, it would make sense that the whole library is copied. And it's also way easier for the compiler. Thanks for the clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

[The GIT of the GNU standard C lib implementation can be found here](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=malloc/malloc.c;h=be472b2ba3885b194f55c29474c4ad5d6a61b729;hb=HEAD).

From this point in the tree you should be able to find [the rest as well](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree).

Comment: Am I right in thinking there is no .c or .cpp file on my Ubuntu file system which contains an implementation for malloc/new? They are contained in a.... .so? file and this is why I must check out the implementation online?

Comment: Yes, the files used to build the C library is not normally included in the distribution - sometimes the source will be included in a separate package that you can install separately, or you can find it on a website like suggested in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The "implementation" is a library you can link (an "a" file or an "so" file) plus an header that contains the declaration (an "h" file).

The C and CPP files sits on the computer that created those libraries before they had been used to build-up your system. And since their source is not required for your programs to work (you just link the binaries, not the sources) they are not distributed together with the system build.

That's why you have to download those files from the source repositories, jut like if you want yourself to rebuild the system.

Answer (score 0):

You find this in the implementation of the C Standard Library the compiler uses.

I'm not sure for Ubunta. Debian's gcc uses eglibc, which's sources [could be found here](http://www.eglibc.org/repository).

Comment: Is there any way to find the implementation within the Filesystem?

Comment: You may also want to look into [MUSL libc](http://musl-libc;org/) whose source code is perhaps easier to read. MUSL libc is an alternative free LibC implementation.

Comment: @user997112: By default the libc-implementations come in binary format, but for the open-source releases the source could be downloaded.